# login using touchscreen software keyboard on raspberry pi

Tags: login, raspberry-pi, touch-screen, gdm3

I am trying to get a keyboard for the login screen but I am having some difficulties. I have tried editing `/etc/lightdm/lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf` as per the page here: [Virtual Keyboard on Login Screen](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=113526)  but it was not working. Another solution was to install gdm3 which I did, but after boot I was met with a black screen. I was given a sort of terminal-like access, but commands were not executed/nothing happened and I am not able to do anything on the Pi, such as wanting to switch back to Lightdm. Is there anyway to fix this issue? (for now I am just going to reinstall). Am I missing dependencies or some critical setting?

Essentially I am doing this so I can boot into a login screen and have the keyboard pop up (so I don't have to use an actual hardware keyboard). Are there any known solutions for this on Lightdm? As it seems gdm3 is the only solution I've seen and I have not been able to get it to work so far.

For reference I am doing this on a raspberry pi 3 model b on the latest raspbian version. I am trying to follow this post here: [Login Using Touchscreen](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/69456/login-using-touchscreen) , but I have not had such luck with it working so far.

Just as a quick update I found that I am able to ssh into the pi and go back to lightdm. Vnc does connect but shows a black screen as well. Here is the view that I get when I connect via hdmi with gdm3: https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4IZP.jpg